# Why is Android Studio updating the wrong jre/bin/java?

Tags: java, android-studio

Updating Android Studio 212.5712.43.2112.8512546 to 213.7172.25.2113.9123335

says

Some conflicts were found in the installation area.

Some of the conflicts below do not have a solution, so the patch cannot be applied. Please download this version from the developer Web site and reinstall it from scratch. Press 'Cancel' to exit.

The error reported is Access denied to jre/bin/java.

Android Studio's own copy of jre/bin/java in ~/Android/android-studio is writeable - I tried touching it. I suspect it's trying to update the operating system's version, which of course is none of its business, and it shouldn't expect a user to be able to change that.

How do I get round this?

Answer (score -1):

Insert your sdk path environment variable

How- Search Bar type- environment variable - edit the system environment variable

02- advanced - environment variable
03- look at down - system variables- path - edit -new - paste your sdk location
04 - press ok

#android_environment_variable